# Why some of existing user not able to see newly added DB in clickhouse

Tags: database, clickhouse, olap, oltp

There is new db created along with tables, but some users are not able to see that particular DB.
What could be the possible reason?

Tried running grant query but 'grant' keyword is also not getting identified in query window.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to see"? Are they able to select it from the `system.databases` table? Do they get some error on some statement? What are the exact statement and error message if so?

Comment: it's fixed, Grant access to db was missing. Thank you @MarkBarinstein